# Do I need a visa to transit through Cuba from Turkey to Haiti?

Tags: transit-visas, cuba, haitian-citizens

I am Haitian currently living in Turkey. Do I need a transit visa to pass through Cuba to go to Haiti?

---

Original question in French:

> Je suis Haïtien,je vis en Turquie, est-ce que j'ai besoin d'un visa
> transit pour passer à cuba pour aller en Haïti ?

Comment: Je me permets de proposer une traduction anglaise de ta question. Pour être utile à la plus grande partie des internautes, les questions posées sur ce site doivent être en anglais.

Answer (score 1):

According to Timatic, the system used by airlines, https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&modify=1 you *can* transit **airside** without a visa. If you need to reclaim your baggage and clear Immigration in Cuba in order to transfer to your onbound flight to Haiti, you *will need* a Tourist visa and a "Declaracion de Sanidad del Viajero”.